# Перевод из формата ASN1_TIME в unixtime

Tags: c, время, openssl

Пытаюсь перевести время из формата ASN1_TIME в unixtime. Время выдергиваю из ssl-сертификата:

```
BIO *bio_mem=BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
BIO_puts(bio_mem,cert);
X509 *x509=PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_mem,NULL,NULL,NULL);
ASN1_TIME* time=X509_get_notBefore(x509);
```

Есть ли какая-нибудь штатная функция? Или уже готовый код?

Comment: связанный вопрос [ASN1_TIME to time_t conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10975542/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы преобразовать время из сертификата (`ASN1_TIME`) в секунды с Эпохи (`time_t`), можно воспользоваться самописной [`ASN1_TIME_to_posix_time()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47015958/4279) или используя несколько обходной путь с уже готовыми функциями:

1. Вызвать `ASN1_TIME_print()`, чтобы получить строку со временем в читаемом формате (`char*` -- `"%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT"`)
2. Вызвать `strptime()`, чтобы получить время, разбитое на части (struct tm -- broken-down time)
3. Получить cекунды с Эпохи (time_t -- calendar time), используя `timegm()`.

Набросок на Си (не тестировано):

```c
time_t ASN1_TIME_to_posix_time(ASN1_TIME* time) {
  // convert YYMMDDHHMMSSZ  (UTCTime <2050) or YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZ (GeneralizedTime) 
  //   to "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT" strptime format (C locale) -- rfc 5280
  time_t posix_time = -1;
  BIO *biobuf = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
  if (!biobuf) goto fail;
  if(!ASN1_TIME_print(biobuf, time)) goto fail;
  // BIO* to char*
  char buf[25]; // "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT" strptime format (C locale).
  if (BIO_gets(biobuf, buf, sizeof(buf)-1) < 0) goto fail;

  // char* to struct tm
  struct tm tm;
  if (!strptime(buf, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT" , &tm)) goto fail;
  // struct tm to time_t
  posix_time = timegm(&tm);

  // fall through
  fail:
  if (biobuf) BIO_free(biobuf);
  return posix_time; // return -1 on error, errno may be set
}
```